# Overwriting array with bigger array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a global array in my program and I want to be able to change it's size at least once in the beginning using a function. Basically like this:

```
pthread_t threadsArray[10]; //default size: 10

void SetMaxThreads(unsigned int count) {
    pthread_t threadsArray[count];
}
```

What would you suggest me to do? How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use standard container `std::vector` instead of the array.

For example

```
std::vector<pthread_t> threadsArray( 10 ); //default size: 10

void SetMaxThreads(unsigned int count) {
    threadsArray.resize( count );
}
```

Comment: Hm, I've never worked with vectors, could you provide an example? Would I have to change my code a lot?

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a dynamic array. This can be done with two different ways. You can either use `std::vector`, or you can use pointers.[Vector Documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). Example using pointers:

```
pthread_t *threadsArray; // no default size

void SetMaxThreads(unsigned int count) {
   delete [] threadsArray;
   threadsArray = new pthread_t[count];
}
```

**Edit:** as some comments pointed out, it is safer to use `std::unique_ptr<pthread_t[]>` instead of array pointers.[`std::unique_ptr` Documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/?kw=unique_ptr)

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<pthread_t[]>` would be better than raw owning pointer.

Comment: This is not exception safe (if `new` throws, `threadsArray` will not point to valid memory). There is a reason why the use of raw pointers is discouraged...